# Error "Command 'next' not found" on Linux-Mint upon executing 'next dev' after first install

Tags: reactjs, linux, next.js

I just installed **`NextJS 10.2`** on my PC running `Linux Mint 20.1` (`Linux Kernel 5.4.0-73-generic`). Upon executing `next dev`, I'm getting the following error.

> Command 'next' not found, but can be installed with:
> sudo apt install mailutils-mh  # version 1:3.7-2.1, or
> sudo apt install mmh           # version 0.4-2
> sudo apt install nmh           # version 1.7.1-6

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "new-next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

I also ran `sudo apt install mailutils-mh` andd tried restarting the server but to no avail. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't need to install a random mail utility package.

Instead, if you're using npm, do

```
npm start dev
```

or if you're using yarn, do

```
yarn dev
```

.

This lets npm or yarn take care of correcting your PATH so your `node_modules/.bin/` is there (and that's where the `next` script lives).